# Count by category and sum it up in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a product collection in MongoDb which sole fields like *_id*, *category*, *user_id*.
I want to check and count the sum number of each category in collection given the matching the *user_id* and then sum up all the count again at the end.

my solution is :

```
return Product.aggregate([
            { $match: { "user_id": "id if user that added the product" } },
            { "$unwind": "$category" },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": {
                        'category': '$category',
                    },
                    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                }
            },
            { "$sort": { "_id.category": 1 } },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$_id.category",
                    "count": { "$first": "$count" }
                }
            }
        ])
```

the code gives me the count of each category without matching the condition of *user_id*. But when I add the *$match* it fails.

Product Schema:

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        default: -1
    },
    category:
    {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    manufactured_by: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user_id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
        required: true
    }
})
```

my result if I dont add the condition:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "A Tables",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "C Tables",
        "count": 4
    },
    {
        "_id": "B Tables",
        "count": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: can you add a sample input data and output data to the question?

Comment: I added the output and I mentioned the input fields needed for operation.

Comment: what's the primary data? add the primary data

Comment: I added the Product Schema. I dont know what do u mean by asking primary data

Comment: a sample document to run your query, go to the database and copy the some doucments

Comment: Check the schema please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228491/discussion-between-devmob-and-mohammad-yaser-ahmadi).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve from the last stage in your pipeline.

But the following should give you desired output (without any complications that you added)

```
async getSellerStatistics(seller_id) {
    return await Product.aggregate([
        { $match: { user_id: seller_id } }
        { $unwind: "$category" },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$category",
                count: { $sum: 1 },
            },
        },
        { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
    ])
}
```

Comment: there are many products in the collection added by many users. I want to count the category with respect to a given user_id.

Comment: my example should do it then

Comment: it gives me empty result.

Comment: and have a look at product schema again.

Comment: are you providing the seller_id correctly as ObjectId?

Comment: $match: { user_id: ObjectId(seller_id) } --> worked

Comment: $match: { user_id: seller_id } --> not working . Dont know why

Comment: seller_id comes as parameter from function